# adding ui with jquery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

my plugin

```
$.fn.myplugin=function(){

var element=$('<div/>').addClass('select').appendTo(this);

return this;
}
```

and script

```
$('<div/>').myplugin().appendTo('body');
```

problem is element not appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/7n2Bd/

But you will have a problem if you are passing a collection of elements. Try this:

```
$.fn.myplugin=function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $('<div>').addClass('select').appendTo(this);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you code is OK.

```
$.fn.myplugin = function() {
    // hello is for just view purpose
    $('<div>hello</div>').addClass('select').appendTo(this);
    return this;
}

$('<div/>').myplugin().appendTo('#target')​; // here instead of '#target' use 'body'
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZAds/6/)**

#### For collection

```
$.fn.myplugin = function() {
    return $.each(this, function() {
       $('<div>hello</div>').addClass('select').appendTo(this);
    });        
}
```

#### Note

Put all your code within `$(document).ready({ .. })`.

Answer (score 1):

add a document ready could help here too

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('<div/>').myplugin().appendTo('body');
    });
```